# Regexp javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to edit my scrip to get only `ref = '521590819123';`

How ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ref = "http://www.site.ru/profile/521590819123";
if( ref.indexOf('profile') >= 0 ) {
  ref = String(ref).substr(ref.indexOf('profile'));
}
alert(ref);
 </script>
```

Comment: `ref = String(ref).substr(ref.indexOf('profile'));` should be `ref = String(ref).substr(ref.indexOf('profile') + 8);` as `profile/` is 8 characters long.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use a regex :

```
var tokens = ref.split('/');
var whatyouwant = tokens[tokens.length-1];
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/7YNRq/)

If you really want to use a regex, you can do

```
var whatyouwant = /([^\/]+$)/.exec(ref)[0];
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8KvL/)

Answer (score 0):

Just change indexof to LastIndexOf

```
ref = String(ref).substr(ref.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lastIndexOf`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ref = "http://www.site.ru/profile/521590819123";
  if( ref.indexOf('profile') >= 0 ) {
    ref = ref.substr(ref.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  }
  alert(ref);
</script>
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/CFeVV/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to resolve this task by regexp, use:

```
 ref = ref.replace(/^.*\/(\d+)$/g, "$1")
```